# Security: direct remote access vs webinterface

Tags: mongodb, security, remote

I need to remotely connect to my (mongoDB) database and I currently allow direct access to the DB server port with user/pw login.

I often read that this is generally a bad idea and that one should rather limit the DB to localhost and use a webinterface (e.g. phpmyadmin, or mongo-express in my case) to allow remote data access.

However, I do not fully understand the advantage of this. Both access methods will have the same permissions for the corresponding user accounts. So an intruder would be able to perform the same operations.

Comment: I think the theory is that you *could* have a web interface that only permits certain operations. If you just have a web interface that accepts any arbitrary SQL, then no, there is really no difference.

Comment: @AaronBertrand OK, that does make sense, but I am generally of the opinion that the permissions should not be handled on the application level but rather be defined within the db itself and therefore limiting the danger of arbitrary SQL queries

Comment: Of course, I was not suggesting that *permissions* were implemented by the app. But you can do both. If you force users to go to through the web interface, they can only do the things you expose to them. You can also do lots of front-end validation etc. before you even bother the database. If you give them a text box where they can just try any old random SQL the user decides to type or paste in, they might still find some loopholes you missed when setting up permissions. So it's kind of like locking your front door in addition to keeping your cash in a safe instead of just relying on the safe

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the clarification.